# $(#cart-continue).click(function) not being called

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cordova

I am simply trying to achieve a navigation to a separate anchor tag when the user clicks the continue button from the cart page.

This is a mobile application using Cordova though this function call is JQuery.

The html is

```
<a id="cart-continue" data-theme="none" class="cart-continue continue-button header-button">Continue</a>
```

The JS in app.js

```
$("#cart-continue").click( function(){
    console.log("**Entered the Click for Continue**");
    if( cart.itemCount() == 0 )
        {
            return false;
        }
    if (Status == "true")
        {
            $.mobile.changePage("#card-message");
        }
    else
        {
            $.mobile.changePage("#may-we-suggest");
        }
});
```

I really haven't seen issues with simple function calls before, we did move the application to a server and call it from the address.
What could be going on to not allow me to use the id of the object appropriate and make the function call?

Comment: Not sure from your context, but did you wrap it in a document.ready?

Comment: I threw your code in a pen and tested it. It works fine.

http://codepen.io/The_Animator/pen/eujtC

Comment: No, its in $(#Page).live(function(){})

Comment: @Derek I see it working fine there though in my code it still is not working, what could the issue be with it not working.....I wouldnt ask the question if i wasnt almost 100% sure the above code would work

Comment: @Keeano That should be telling you that the problem is not with that code, it is with other existing code that you have in place. Nobody can identify the problem without the problem code.

Comment: Try $(document).on('click', '#cart-continue', function(){});

Comment: Oh, alright.....Do you know where a good place to start looking? i did write full full document and its over 6,000 lines. This is the code specifically for this page

Comment: Not a solution, but "As of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated. Use .on() to attach event handlers. Users of older versions of jQuery should use .delegate() in preference to .live()." [jquery api](http://api.jquery.com/live/)

Comment: Try to check if this part of code is called, maybe problem is not in binding method (add console.log right before $("#cart-continue").click...)

Comment: `#cart-continue` must not be available when `app.js` runs so the event handler is never attached.

Comment: The reason it works on the code pen example is because it is a div. He is using an anchor tag. You will need to prevent the default event of the anchor tag. See my answer. This has had me banging my head against the wall before too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an easy mistake to make. You need the stop the default event of the anchor tag. Do this:

```
$("#cart-continue").click( function( e ){
    e.preventDefault()
    console.log("**Entered the Click for Continue**");
    if( cart.itemCount() == 0 )
        {
            return false;
        }
    if (Status == "true")
        {
            $.mobile.changePage("#card-message");
       }
    else
        {
            $.mobile.changePage("#may-we-suggest");
        }
 });
```

Comment: Thnaks, that helped out quit a bit!